# How to make a physical rope which is on drag move and rotate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics, unityscript

I have make a rope with a model having 41 small bone, one bone is children of another one i.e 2nd bone is children of 1st one , 3rd bone is children of 2nd and so on. I add hinge joint on each bone and connected to 1st to 2nd , 2nd to 3rd and so on. Finally a make a rope, this work fine until i didn't manipulate it on mouse drag. I want this rope to roll on a cylinder object, cylinder is a static gameobject and i didn't want it to move. What i want is if i drag one end of rope it will roll on cylinder and make tie, but the problem is it don't behave as i thought, it makes rope all glitchy and weird.

What's the best way to do this sort of thing? Thanks in advance!

Here a snapshot of my model

[image: Rope Scene]

Comment: Is it possible to post a picture of your rope?

Comment: @aGer ..picture added